# Switching to File Sharing enabled false

Tags: ios, info.plist, file-sharing

I have an app already released to the store and I do not want to have my Documents folder visible to the end user in iTunes. Is there any potential issues from switching the Bool from true in the app store version to false for an update?

All existing apps won't see have any issues? I tried googling and couldn't see any mention of this causing a problem but just wondering if there's anything I need to worry about

Answer (score 0):

I've made the experience that that's not a problem. Users of the old version still see the Documents folder of the app in iTunes, while users who update do not see the folder anymore.

Also, nothing changes to the files in the Documents folder. Files that are located there remain there, no matter if they were created by the app or if they were copied by the user via iTunes.